# Image reload into canvas

Tags: javascript, html

The goal of the code is as follows:

- upload an image to a file
- the user draws 4 points by clicking on the image
- the x, y coordinates of the points are saved in an array

Now I have made a reset button in case the user is wrong to indicate the points.
The reset button should erase the array and reload the original image in the canvas.
I tried to invoke the function again but does not reload the image.

I'm new in javascript.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Title
     <p id="demo"></p>
  </h2>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <input type='file' id="fileUpload"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="resetButton" onclick="resetPoint()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>

    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
 </div>



<script>
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function readImage() {
    if ( this.files && this.files[0] ) {
     var percorso = this.files[0]
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           var img = new Image();
           img.src = e.target.result;
           img.onload = function() {
             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,500,500);
           };
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL( this.files[0] );
    }
}

fileUpload.onchange = readImage;

var coordinate=[];

    canvas.onclick = function(e) {
      if (coordinate.length < 4) {
        var x = e.offsetX;
        var y = e.offsetY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font="25px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(coordinate.length+1,x+2, y+2);

       var coordinataN=[x,y];

       coordinate.push(coordinataN);

       var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
      }
    };

function resetPoint() {

 readImage()


  coordinate.length = 0;
  alert("Points deleted");

}




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas first, then do your redrawing of the image.

You can clear the canvas by doing the following:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

You can add this line at the begining of your `resetPoint()` function.

Now that you want to keep the image, you need to save the uploaded image file somewhere so you can redraw it. I suggest making a variable outside your `resetPoint()` function:

`var files;`

and then at the beginning of your `resetPoint()` function add:

`files = this.file`

Aswell as change all the references to `this.files` to files.

See the snippet below for a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Title
     <p id="demo"></p>
  </h2>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
     <input type='file' id="fileUpload"/>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="resetButton" onclick="resetPoint()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
     <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>

    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">Footer</div>
 </div>



<script>
var fileUpload = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var files; // Add this
var img = new Image();
function readImage() {
    files = this.files; // Set a reference to this.files (the image)
    if (files && files[0] ) { // Update this line to only reference the files variable
        var percorso = files[0]; // And this line
        var FR= new FileReader();
        FR.onload = function(e) {
           img.src = e.target.result;
           img.onload = function() {
             ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,500,500);
           };
        };
        FR.readAsDataURL( files[0] ); // And this line
    }
}

fileUpload.onchange = readImage;

var coordinate=[];

    canvas.onclick = function(e) {
      if (coordinate.length < 4) {
        var x = e.offsetX;
        var y = e.offsetY;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.font="25px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(coordinate.length+1,x+2, y+2);

       var coordinataN=[x,y];

       coordinate.push(coordinataN);

       var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
      }
    };

function resetPoint() {
  

 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
 readImage()


  coordinate.length = 0;
  alert("Points deleted");

}




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nik! With the reset button I would simply reload the same image previously chosen by the user so that him can redraw the points from the beginning.

Comment: @zephod17 Ah, okay. I've updated my answer to answer that part of the question

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you Nik!